# PostgreSQL merge query for update stock information - syntax error at or near "MERGE"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, **main_table** has *product_id*, *product_stock* and *product_name* columns.

**update_table** has *product_id*, *product_stock* columns.

I want to update *product_stock* for **main_table**.

I wrote this query:

```
MERGE INTO main_table MT
USING update_table UT
ON MT.product_id = UT.product_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET MT.product_stock = UT.product_stock ;
```

But this query returning with error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MERGE"
```

Why my query is not working and how can i make this work ?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) there is no MERGE command in Postgres. It seems you want a normal UPDATE statement instead.

Comment: The MERGE command was introduced into v15, which will not be released for a month or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have indicated Postgres does not (yet) have the `merge` statement.  However, you do not need it. Your statement will update the `main_table` for the `product_id` from the `update_table` that *exist in main_table*, however if the product_id in update_table does not exist in main_table, the statement bypasses the update and continues. This is because an attempt to update a non-existing row *is not an error*.  Postgres does the same thing with `update ... from ...` So:   (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1247ec85979395fb9139f03fdd608bcf))

```
update main_table mt  
   set product_stock = ut.product_stock
  from update_table ut
 where ut.product_id = mt.product_id;
```

The downside being you get no notification of the updates that did not happen. But then Merge does not give a notice either.